# Trigger stimulus event when target added/removed from DOM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails, hotwire, turbo-frames

I have what is essentially a form with multiple pages, where there is a partial which renders the form content for each page inside of a partial that contains the header, footer, "next" button.

I need my "Next" button to respond dynamically to each page. So if the user is viewing Page 1 of the form, then I'm checking that the fields (targets) on Page 1 are not empty before enabling the "Next" button, at which point they move on to Page 2, and the next button should be disabled again until all of the fields/targets on Page 2 have been completed.

So the controller should be able to fire a function each time the page change happens, which I figured I could do by detecting when certain targets are present on the DOM. But I haven't been able to find a straightforward way to do this.

This is more or less a stripped down version of what I have

The outer wrapper:

```
  <body data-controller="next-button">

    <main>
      <%= turbo_frame_tag :main, do %>
        <%= yield %>
      <% end %>
    </main>

      <%= render partial: 'application/progress_bar' %>
    <% end %>
  </body>
```

Then I also have a rails form with a text field:

```
<%= form.text_field :name, data: { target: "next-button.contactName"}  %>
```

This is my controller:

```
export default class extends Controller {
static targets = ['contactName']

  connect() {
    console.log(this.contactNameTarget);
  }

  contactNameTargetConnected() {
    console.log('foo');
  }

}
```

When the page loads, `console.log(this.contactNameTarget)` outputs the HTML for contactName as expected, but `contactNameTargetConnected()` does nothing.

Based on the [stimulus documentation](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/lifecycle-callbacks) regarding lifecycle callbacks, I would expect this function to fire on load, especially since it clearly can access `this.contactNameTarget`

I also looked at a posted solution from the stimulus team on [github](https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus/issues/200) where they have an example that looks like it could solve my issue, but the code they've posted is deprecated, and I was not able to get it working:

```
const event = document.createEvent("CustomEvent")
event.initCustomEvent("inner-connected", true, true, null)
this.element.dispatchEvent(event)
```

Comment: can you add your generated html here?